# How to construct the scheme below?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

How can one construct the diagram shown below, using just a ruler and a compass, where $ \angle PYX = 2\angle PXY $ and $ \angle PYZ = 2\angle PZY $:

[image]

Comment: The ratio is simply the ratio of the angles, that is, $\angle PXY : \angle PZY$. I don't know whether the angles are unique though!

Answer (score 1):

The ratio doesn't seem to be anything special, but depends on the size of the angles in the triangle.

Let $M$ be the intersection of $YP$ and $XZ$. Using the cotangent formula or m-n rule, you can get the ratio $$\frac{XM}{MZ}=\frac{\sin ZPY\cos PXY}{\sin XPY\cos PZY}$$

Comment: The thing is, I'm trying to construct such a situation using a compass and a ruler, and I don't know where to go if I can't construct the line PY first...but thank you for the answer

Comment: @Fermat maybe you should pose the question again, rephrased accordingly and with the appropriate tags.

Comment: Done! Tagged under "Geometric-Construction" as well now

Answer (score 1):

A locus of points $P$ such that $\angle PYZ = 2 \angle PZY$ is a certain hyperbola.

A locus of poins $P$ such that $\angle PYX = 2\angle PXY$ is another hyperbola.

Finding an intersection of two hyperbolas is essentially a [Problem of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius). So the only thing left is to identify them.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: But how can you draw a parabola with a compass and ruler?

Comment: @Fermat Don't _draw_ them. You only need to find an intersection. Again, check out how the Apollonius problem is solved.

Comment: So I read through how the Apollonius problem is solved - all about how the difference d1-d2 is constant. However, I still don't understand how to apply it to our situation here. Also, in the same page which you linked it says "A second hyperbola can be drawn for the pair...", so you have to draw it?